# Multiple select menus onChange update specific select menu by name through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which allows you to update a products main category and sub category through select menus.
The options in the sub category select menu change depending on the main category selected through a ajax db call.
I can get this to work perfectly through the below JQuery script if the form contains only one product.
However if the form contains multiple products. every products sub category select menu also changes to the same set of options

for example: on a single Product which is say orange juice
Main categories = Fruit, salad, beverages
If I select beverages for example
the sub category menu options correctly updates  to: Glass, can, carton, bottle
That's all good

however if the form contains multiple products all their sub category options also update to: Glass, can, carton, bottle

I know this is because the dynamically generated select  name attribute for each sub category uses the same name (see example html form below).

The form and products are generated dynamically through PHP and the number of products can vary from 1 to say whatever...
So my question is how do I change the below script to update the correct products sub category menu options without effecting the other products sub category menu options?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name='Category']").change(function() {
    var CategoryID = $("select[name='Category'] option:selected").val();
    var SubCategoryID = $("select[name='SubCategory'] option:selected").val();    

    if (CategoryID) {     
              $.ajax({
                url: '/__Dependencies/JQuery/GetSubCategories2.script.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {Category: CategoryID, SubCategory: SubCategoryID},
                cache: false
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("select[name='SubCategory']").html(data);
                });
                }
    });
```

Revised  JQuery to the below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("select[name='Category']").change(function () {
     const SelectorName = $(this);
    const Category = $(this).val();
    const $SubCategory = $(this).next();

    // Check that a selector with the name "Category" exists in the html document
    if (!SelectorName) {
      alert("The selector name does not exist in the HTML document!");
    }

    // Validate that field is not empty before AJAX call
    if ($.trim($("Category")) != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/__Dependencies/JQuery/GetSubCat.script.php',
        data: {
          Category: Category,
        },
        cache: false
      }).done(function(data) {
        $SubCategory.html(data);
      });
    }
    });
});

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="updateProducts" action="file.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="Category">Cocoa Cola 330ml</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="Category" id="Category">
                        <option value="8">Bakery</option>
                        <option value="11" selected="selected">Beverages</option>
                        <option value="9">Meat</option>
                        <option value="10">Poultry</option>
                        <option value="1">Vegetables</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="SubCategory" id="SubCategory">
                        <option value="7">Cans</option>
                        <option value="8">Bottles</option>
                        <option value="2">cartons</option>
                        <option value="4">Glass</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">update</button>
                </div></li>

            <li><label for="Category">Cocoa Cola 500ml</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="Category" id="Category">
                        <option value="8">Bakery</option>
                        <option value="11" selected="selected">Beverages</option>
                        <option value="9">Meat</option>
                        <option value="10">Poultry</option>
                        <option value="1">Vegetables</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="SubCategory" id="SubCategory">
                        <option value="7">Cans</option>
                        <option value="8">Bottles</option>
                        <option value="2">cartons</option>
                        <option value="4">Glass</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">update</button>
                </div></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
});
```

Comment: This does not make any sense - in the event that is triggered on the element you test if the element that triggered the event you are in exists. `$("select[name='Category']").change(function () {
     const SelectorName = $(this);`

Comment: You maybe mean `if ($SubCategory) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. UNIQUE IDs (or don't use IDs)
2. This will update ALL subcats on the page `$("select[name='SubCategory']").html(data);`
3. Use relative addressing

I would personally also add a "please select" option 0 and test that the val was empty before ajaxing

Have a look at this first

```js
$(function() {
  $(".Category]").on("change", function() {
    const category = $(this).val();
    const $subCategorySel = $(this).next(); // sibling element, here the related SubCategory select

    if (category) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/__Dependencies/JQuery/GetSubCategories2.script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          Category: category,
        },
        cache: false
      }).done(function(data) {
        $subCategorySel.html(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="updateProducts" action="file.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="Category">Cocoa Cola 330ml</label>
      <div>
        <select name="Category" class="Category">
          <option value="8">Bakery</option>
          <option value="11" selected="selected">Beverages</option>
          <option value="9">Meat</option>
          <option value="10">Poultry</option>
          <option value="1">Vegetables</option>
        </select>
        <select name="SubCategory" class="SubCategory">
          <option value="7">Cans</option>
          <option value="8">Bottles</option>
          <option value="2">cartons</option>
          <option value="4">Glass</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">update</button>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li><label for="Category">Cocoa Cola 500ml</label>
      <div>
        <select name="Category" class="Category">
          <option value="8">Bakery</option>
          <option value="11" selected="selected">Beverages</option>
          <option value="9">Meat</option>
          <option value="10">Poultry</option>
          <option value="1">Vegetables</option>
        </select>
        <select name="SubCategory" class="SubCategory">
          <option value="7">Cans</option>
          <option value="8">Bottles</option>
          <option value="2">cartons</option>
          <option value="4">Glass</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">update</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Mplugian, your solution worked perfectly. Can you explain what const $SubCategorySel = $(this).next();
is doing? 
The var SubCategoryID = $("select[name='SubCategory'] option:selected").val(); 
is no longer necessary. It was accidently left in from my attempts to trouble shoot.

Comment: So $(this) in the event handler for the Category is the Category select. $(this).next() is the next sibling, which means the related SubCategory select

Comment: Hi Mplugian, Forget my last comment (deleted).  The revised JQuery seems to be working fine.  The issue is that the PHP script fails to see the ajax post variables.
If I load the script page in the browser and echo the POST value I get notice undefined index... and var_dump says empty...
However echoing <option>$_POST['Category']</option> updates the sub category select with the correct value...